# Understanding script

Tags: shell-script

I need understand this:

```
df -ah >/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt
find . -type f  -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nr -k 5  >>/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt&id=$!
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash
#recolecta.sh
date;echo 'Command is running, it will cost about 10 minutes, please wait...'
cd /opt/
df -ah >/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt
find . -type f  -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nr -k 5  >>/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt&
id=$!
char=("-" "/" "|" "\\") 
n=0 
while ps -ef |grep "$id" |grep -v grep > /dev/null 
do
       echo -ne "\rCommand is running, it will cost about 10 minutes, please wait...${char[$n]} " 
        n=$(( (n+1)%4 )) 
        sleep 1 
done
ls -lht -R >>/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt
tree >>/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt
REMOTE_HOST=$(getOMUName|grep REMOTE_HOST|awk -F '='  '{print $2}')
ssh $REMOTE_HOST
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as text instead of a picture, and ask a specific question: what part do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific in your question.
If I understood it well, you have doubt about the `df` and `find` commands in the bash script. So, here is a explanation:

```
df -ah >/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt
```

- Report file system disk usage, including pseudo, duplicate and inaccessible file systems (`-a`) in human readable format (`-h`), then create (or overwrite) a file named  `Active_directory.txt`with the output.

`find . -type f  -exec ls -l {} \; | sort -nr -k 5 >>/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt & id=$!`

- Find in current directory any matchs of `file type`, execute `ls -l` (long list) for each matching file, sorting the output by numeric order of column 5 and reversing it (That means: Bigger files first). Then, append the output to the file `/opt/pub/software/tmp/Active_directory.txt`. This whole command is executed in background (`&`). The PID of this job (`$!`) is saved in a variable named `id`.